# Creating a windows service to execute code on time

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-services

I need a solution to a problem I'm having. I have to automatically run some C# code at exactly 12 o clock am every night to make changes to a database. I've heard the way to do this is with a windows service, but I truly have no idea where to begin with this. 
I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS and the database is hosted on SQL Server Express. 
What can I do to solve my problem, with or without a windows service? Thanks!

Comment: You could use Windows Task Scheduler. A web service sounds unnecessary.

Comment: Web services have nothing to do with scheduled code execution.

Comment: I only said that because of this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

Comment: Write a simple console app in C# to make the required changes.  Use Task Scheduler to schedule it.

Comment: Example of task scheduler? If you don't mind... Never heard of this so not sure what this entails?

Comment: It's just a built in tool for Windows that executes programs on a schedule of your choosing. See [MS Documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). It's fairly easy to use, I don't think you'll need to ask for our help on using it (apart from maybe having to convert your web service to a console app).

Comment: Link refers to Win7, but it also exists for Windows Server.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: You can use windows service as well instead of doing it in web service

Comment: I think I meant windows service, not web service, oops...

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this using a timer, then you can run it in your web service or whatever

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

```
      private void InitTimer(){
       System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
       timer.Interval = CalculateInterval();
       timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onElapsed);

            timer.Start();
      }

    private double CalculateInterval()
       {
         TimeSpan sleeptime = default(TimeSpan);           
         sleeptime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(yourInterval);
         return sleeptime.TotalMilliseconds;
       }
   private void onElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       //do something
    }

   }
```